# Radio button not clickable and displaying like a solid bullet. How to solve it?

Tags: html, flask

I am using Flask framework. I am fetching values as a list from flask using render template and using for loop in html to display the list values with radio button.In HTML, Radio button is not clickable and displaying like a solid bullet.

Comment: Please Add some code..What you have done?

Comment: I am fetching values as a list from flask using render template and using for loop in html to deisplay the list values with radio button.

Comment: You just need to update your markup.....You can get help with the markup, I provided in Answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new in HTML. Please have a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp)
You can try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other  
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it wasn't tagged but op mentions Flask framework... and not much else...